# Trouble with Boot Repair/BIOS Compatibility

Tags: bios, boot-repair

I am receiving this error after going through boot-repair commands. When I change my BIOS settings to UEFI I cannot boot from USB. Has anyone experienced this or have any pointers for what settings I may have incorrect that would fix it?

[image]

Comment: There is a similar post related to your question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636793/boot-repair-cant-boot-ubuntu-in-uefi-mode)

Comment: How did you make USB flash drive? Some tools like Rufus only make UEFI or only BIOS versions from Ubuntu ISO. Other tools make a flash drive that can boot in either mode, but then you have select in UEFI one time boot menu the "UEFI:entry" not plain "entry" where entry is name or label of flash drive. Best to use Ubuntu live installer in live mode & add Boot-Repair using ppa to that.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair